# How to get current Button text color in Android?

Tags: android, button

I cant figure out how to get the current color of the text of a Button. I know its probably this but cant quite figure out the parameters.

```
public static int getTextColor (Context context, TypedArray attrs, int def)...
```

Basically Im trying to do this

```
if(text is RED)
{make text BLACK}
else
{make text RED}
```

I know how to set the text color.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this

```
ColorStateList mList = mButton.getTextColors();
int color = mList.getDefaultColor();

switch(color)
{
case Color.RED:
mButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
break;

case Color.BLACK:
mButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
break;

}
```

Comment: mButton.getTextColors().getDefaultColor() gives me -1

Comment: -1 refers to Color.WHITE ... mList.getDefaultColor()  returns a constant value for a Color.

Comment: Why they have `getCurrentTextColor()` and `getDefaultColor()` both? Apparently they both does the same!

Comment: @66CLSjY how to get the integer for hex color?

Comment: @Reza, Can you elaborate?