# How to get button text color in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, textview, android-button

I'm looking for a way to dynamically get the button text color. I found this from here [How to get current Button text color in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210611/how-to-get-current-button-text-color-in-android)

```
ColorStateList mList = mButton.getTextColors();
int color = mList.getDefaultColor();

switch(color)
{
case Color.RED:
mButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
break;

case Color.BLACK:
mButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
break;
}
```

This code gives me some integer constants for example -1 is Color.WHITE but I want a more general way to get the hex integer value of the color and not just some constants.

Comment: no the color here is a constant integer, for example when the value is -1 it means that the color is white, I want to hex integer value

Comment: yes but I only can access specific range of colors like Color.Black and Color.Red not all the colors. I don't want to be limited to this colors.

Comment: I'm not creating the colors and I don't have argb to create the color from. I get a constant integer from mButton.getTextColors().getDefaultColor() from that integer (say -1 or anything else) I want to get the color hex value or Color object. That's my problem

Answer (score 1):

To get the current color of the button's text try to use this method:
`mButton.getCurrentTextColor();`